# Grep a word in the file and then search backward for a pattern

Tags: awk, sed, grep, find

I have a file in which I have to search for a word and as soon as I find that word , I have to keep that record in my output and also I need to go back from that record and take a previous record as well , below is the example

```
insert_job: Capture this record as well   job_type: FW
box_name:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
machine: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
owner: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
permission:
date_conditions: 0
description: "This job waits for .trg file of CRH load file. This job waits for 2 hrs and alarms Ops."
term_run_time: 121
box_terminator: 1
max_run_alarm: 120
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
timezone: CentralTime
watch_file: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
watch_interval: 30
```

In the above jil as soon as I find the watch_file keyword then i need to go back and capture the job name as well which is in insert_job section. I have multiple jils in a file and need to find and write in to the output file.

Comment: Hi and welcome to unix.SE! As your question stands it probably can't be answered. Can you please explain what a "jil" is, what your expected output is, and show the code you have so far?

Comment: Thanks all for your response, @Theophrastus:- Yes , If we capture tha job name and dump whenever we  get the watch_file matched. Can you please show me a way for it .

Comment: share the expected output.

Comment: The expected output is     insert_job: Capture this record as well                         watch_file: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"   for each match.

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`:

If you want to capture entire lines containing the keyword:

```
 awk  '/^insert_job|^watch_file/' file
```

which could also be done with `grep`:

```
grep -E '^insert_job|^watch_file' file
```

If you want to only capture the fields after the keywords `insert_job:` and `watch_file:`, use option `-F` to set the field separator:

```
awk -F'[^ ]*: *' '/^insert_job/{a=$2}/^watch_file/{print a, $2}' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, I used the first one to print entire line and it is giving me only first 6 records while we have more ten 1900 in the file , Can you please suggest , I used below code                                                                                                               awk -F'[^ ]*: *' '/^insert_job/{a=$2}/^watch_file/{print a, $2}' /home/nbdhbfy/CSDI_CRH_job.txt >> output.txt

Comment: @SumitC Please try the `grep`command I added to this post.

Comment: @SumitC Are the keywords `insert_job` and `watch_file` always at the beginning of the line?

Comment: Thanks oliv for your response-Watch_file and Insert_job will be at the location/Position I shown in the sample data However the position is not fixed it may vary depending on the definition.